# Makefile: Need clarity on mixed usage of environment variable and make variables

Tags: makefile

I am basically looking into a buggy makefile, which confused me with the following scenario.

```
default:
     echo "Build started with $@ at $(ENV_VAR)";\
     ENV_VAR=$(NEW_DIR); \
     cd $(ENV_VAR); \
     $(MAKE);
```

***Objective of the programmer:***

Basically the programmer has intended to override the environment variable **ENV_VAR** with a new value (path to a directory) **NEW_DIR** and then execute make recursively within that directory.

***Bug in this makefile:***

The bug that I see is the coder has used **"cd $(ENV_VAR)"** instead of **"cd $$(ENV_VAR)"**. So because of this, we haven't actually used the overriden make variable for "cd" command instead still using the value of environment variable   before executing $(MAKE). Also the cd command failed because of non-existing path.Finally we end up doing a recursive make.

***Questions I have***

As I mentioned in the above paragraph, we are in the scenario of recursive make. Interestingly What I see is when the same target is called for the second time I see the $(ENV_VAR) to reflect the overridden value of NEW_DIR.That's making me puzzled.

***Sample Output:***

Assume:

NEW_DIR=/new-dir OLD-DIR=/old-dir

Output:

```
Build started with default at /old-dir
bin/sh /old-dir: no such file (or) directory
Build started with default at /new-dir
```

Any suggestions on this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that `$(ENV_VAR)` is incorrect. But `$$(ENV_VAR)` is incorrect too.

Make expands the variables in the command, then passes the command to the shell, which does its own expansion. So

```
default:
     echo "Build started with $@ at $(ENV_VAR)";\
     ENV_VAR=$(NEW_DIR); \
     cd $(ENV_VAR); \
     $(MAKE);
```

becomes a shell command

```
echo "Build started with $@ at /old_dir";\
ENV_VAR=/new_dir; \
cd /old_dir; \
make
```

This command has not yet been executed; the assignment has not yet taken place, and it's already too late.

The proposed solution won't work either. This:

```
default:
     echo "Build started with $@ at $(ENV_VAR)";\
     ENV_VAR=$(NEW_DIR); \
     cd $$(ENV_VAR); \
     $(MAKE);
```

becomes this:

```
echo "Build started with $@ at /old_dir";\
ENV_VAR=/new_dir; \
cd $(ENV_VAR); \
make
```

This looks good, but notice that `cd $(ENV_VAR);` is *Make* syntax, not shell syntax (at least not bash). The correct shell syntax is `cd $ENV_VAR`, so the rule should be:

```
default:
     echo "Build started with $@ at $(ENV_VAR)";\
     ENV_VAR=$(NEW_DIR); \
     cd $$ENV_VAR; \
     $(MAKE);
```

According to [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Environment), "by default, only variables that came from the environment or the command line are passed to recursive invocations" (but you can override this behavior if you choose). Since `ENV_VAR` is an environmental variable, it will be passed to the sub-make, and if you modify it in the command shell, the sub-make will receive the modified value.

Finally, I suggest you try it this way:

```
default:
    echo "Build started with $@ at $(ENV_VAR)";
    Make -C $(NEW_DIR) ENV_VAR=$(NEW_DIR);
```